# Function sleep when animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm using `[UIView transitionWithView:]` for animation.

This method don't have `delay` only duration, but I need to have some delay.

For example: Need to change 1 image to another with duration 1 sec, then after 4 second change image to another with duration 1 second.

I know about `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` that have `delay` but i don't change frame it don't change image for more then 1 time.

I use next:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration: 1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                       //here change image
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 4.0f];
}];
```

It's work fine. But it I change view ( I have scrollView and added a lot of view with animation) it show another view and it's own animation but `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 4.0f];` from previous page work on it's to.

So how I can make delay for my animation?

**Thanks for help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like to rely on timers. They don't hang the app and give you more flexibility to control your triggers.

```
NSTimer *mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myAnimationFunction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void) myAnimationFunction:(NSTimer *)timer{<br>
   // Do anything here...<br>
}
```

Comment: I don't sure that using timer good if you have 5 images to change a lot of times so you need to create 5 method's.

Comment: you don't need multiple methods. Inside the same method you can use a switch selector and refer back to the same method until you change the last image.